# How to alter the table's encoding in the Sequel Pro?

Tags: mysql

How to alter the Mysql table's encoding in the Sequel Pro?

in the table, I want to add a row data, and the character is Chinese, but I can not add, because the encoding is not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figure out the solution:

1. If want to change the table's encoding, should in the Table Info tab :

[image]

And should make sure the Table Structure fields's encoding.

2. If what to change the mysql's Code set, find the mysql install place, and find the mysql's configuration file (`my.cnf`) 
   Under the `[client]`, add the below config:

   ```
   default-character-set=utf8
   init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
   ```

and restart the mysql.

so in the mysql make sure:

```
>show variables like 'character%'; 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+ 
| character_set_client | utf8 | 
| character_set_connection | utf8 | 
| character_set_database | utf8 | 
| character_set_filesystem | binary | 
| character_set_results | utf8 | 
| character_set_server | utf8 | 
| character_set_system | utf8 | 
| character_sets_dir | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ | 
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Then there will not get messy code.